# Exception after upgrading .net compact framework version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compact-framework, pocketpc

I have upgraded my project from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5 through visual studio `Project-> Upgrade Project .` 
After upgrade when i compile the project i got the error

```
'The type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridTableStyle' exists in both 'c:\Users\VijayVignesh\Desktop\AGMobile4\Dll\Other\System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Windows.Forms.dll''.
```

Typically two dlls are refernced in my project `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.dll`. So, i decided to remove `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.dll` from the project.

And when i run the project ,

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ImageList imgLstSplashScrn;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(SplashScreen));
    this.mainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu();
    this.picBxCompLogo = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    this.lblWait = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.imgLstSplashScrn = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList();
    this.SuspendLayout();

}
```

i get the exception '`Exception was unhandled`' at `'this.imgLstSplashScrn = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList();'`

When i try to handle the exception on `InitializeComponent()` call , i get the exception `'ObjectDisposedException was unhandled'`.

How do i solve it ??

Comment: Did you change the target framework of the project?

Comment: Yea i tried changing different platforms still i get same error .

Comment: Also i get no symbols are loaded for any call stack frame error at some target platform.

Comment: I ma missing the Forms.Controls.Add lines from this Designer.cs. Can you post the full code? Further on, what did you really reference? The 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Windows.Forms.dll' is the correct one.

Comment: Yes that was the problem , while converting vs2008 referenced dll from its src.I had dll referece inside my project.Re refereced the dll and it worked.