# Best way to upgrade a .NET Compact Version Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compact-framework

I am developing a windows mobile application using .NET Compact framework v2.0.
Now i need to upgrade my project to  .NET Compact framework v3.5.

I have tried updating the project from Visual Studio Project->Upgrade Project.
It converts to .NET Compact framework v3.5.But when i compile it throws lots of error.

Is anything wrong with my upgrade process ?? Or should i end up with clearing all the errors.

I have already posted another question on the error that i get ([Exception after upgrading .net compact framework version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256851/exception-after-upgrading-net-compact-framework-version)) But i want to know whether my upgrade process is right ??

Comment: Generally upgrade shouldn't cause errors unless there are breaking changes(will be very less with msft). What are the errors you get?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256851/exception-after-upgrading-net-compact-framework-version

Comment: @user3383301 if you already have another question open, don't duplicate it.